# Slow boot Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, kernel

> $ systemd-analyze

```
Startup finished in 40.697s (kernel) + 4.284s (userspace) = 44.981s graphical.target reached after 4.267s in userspace
```

> UPD: I'll try it and write about the results 
>   https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=286950
>
> after

```
wpa_supplicant[1063]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get
wpa_supplicant[1063]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
pulseaudio[1857]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
```

> UPD

```
7.880061] raid6: .... xor() 6285 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    7.880086] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
[    7.884211] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx       
[    7.906852] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
[   40.245629] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   40.268904] random: crng init done
[   40.268941] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   40.479264] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   40.487462] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SEL
```

Comment: Sorry, your question was not clear to me. Could you detail it?

Comment: Linux mint started to boot for a long time.